# Add-ADGroupMember problem with adding multiple Groups at once

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My current problem is, that when i want to add Groups to a Group it gives me a ParameterBindingException. This is what i have so far:

```
$MissingGroup = 'GGroup01'

$getADGroupSplat = @{
    # find all groups where `$MissingGroup` is NOT a member of
    LDAPFilter = '(!memberof={0})' -f (Get-ADGroup $MissingGroup).DistinguishedName
    SearchBase = 'OU=xxxxxxxxxxx,DC=xxxxxxxxxxxxx,DC=xx'
}

$Group = Get-ADGroup @getADGroupSplat

$actualGroup = $Group | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "GGroup_A0*_Security"} | Format-List Name

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $MissingGroup -Members $actualGroup
```

Can someone help me?

The error is:

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Der Parameter "Members" kann nicht gebunden werden. Objekt vom Typ "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPrincipal. Der Adapter kann den Wert 
der Name-Eigenschaft nicht festlegen." kann nicht erstellt werden.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:61
+ ... -ADGroup -Identit $CitrixGG | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $actualGroup
+                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

The error is in german.

Comment: For a start don't use `Format-List`. It's not needed. Post the actual exception.

Comment: Did you remove `Format-List` from the `$actualGroup` object and try it?

Comment: Yeah it actually worked with removing the Format-List. But I don't understand what diffrence it makes.

Comment: `Format-List` turns the data into a bunch of serial formatting data that describes what to _write to the screen buffer_. You want to pass the original object(s) around, not formatting data :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `Format-List`. It's for writing the data to the screen.

Here's your code updated:

```
$MissingGroup = 'GGroup01'
$getADGroupSplat = @{
    # find all groups where `$MissingGroup` is NOT a member of
    LDAPFilter = '(!memberof={0})' -f (Get-ADGroup $MissingGroup).DistinguishedName
    SearchBase = 'OU=xxxxxxxxxxx,DC=xxxxxxxxxxxxx,DC=xx'
}
$Group = Get-ADGroup @getADGroupSplat
$actualGroup = $Group | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "GGroup_A0*_Security"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $MissingGroup -Members $actualGroup -MemberIdentity (Get-ADGroupMember $actualGroup).SamAccountName
```